# How to create confirm yes/no in php?

Tags: php, message

I want to create a confirm yes/no box in php
my code like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
{
?>

<script>
 var cf=confirm("do you want to delete Y/N");
 if(cf)
  { i want to call code edit of php

  }
</script>
<?php
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm" method="post" action="edit.php">
<a href="edit.php?id=1">Edit </a> <br>
<a href="edit.php?id=2">Edit </a> <br>
<a href="edit.php?id=3">Edit </a> <br>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I Want to when press Yes i call code edit in PHP
But it do not work.
Can you help me ?
Thanks you

Comment: use inline `onclick` event

Answer (score 9):

In your code, you have mentioned PHP but, have used JavaScript.

**If you want to do a confirm with PHP,**

Create an intermediate page for confirmation.

Post form data there.

On confirmation page, add two submit buttons:

`Yes`: If pressed this, redirect/post to edit page.

`No`: If pressed this, redirect back to form

So, your confirmation page should be:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
    if ($_POST['confirm'] == 'Yes') {
        header("Location:edit.php?id=1");
    }
    else if ($_POST['confirm'] == 'No') {
        header("goBack.php");
    } 
}
?>

<form method="post">
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
{
?>
<input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Yes"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="confirm" value="No"><br/>
<?php
}
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use inline onclick event.

This is a simple techique, you can use it in your PHP page.

```
<a href="edit.php?id=1" onclick="return  confirm('do you want to delete Y/N')">Edit </a>
```

Comment: Perhaps it may be a bit obvious, but it's good to point that if he does this, then he does not need the code in between the `script` tags. In addition, this solution could be done to all `a` tags with jQuery. +1

Comment: While I like this method for the user, if you a doing a delete id with this method, a HTML spider/link checker will still find this link with a GET, rather than a POST and kill the id record anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Put an id on your form:

Create an event listener for the form's `onsubmit` event

```
<script>
   function onFormSubmission(e){
       return confirm("do you want to delete Y/N");
   }

   var frm = document.getElementById('frm');
   frm.addEventListener("submit", onFormSubmission);
</script>
```

When the user submits a form they will be prompted with your message. If they click Yes the function will return true and the form will be submitted. Otherwise the function will return false and the form submission will be cancelled

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
<?php
//YOU MUST BE SURE THAT YOUR URL CONTAINS THE $_REQUEST['id'] PARAMETER, OTHERWISE IT WON'T WORK FROM YOUR CODE... IF YOU WANT IT TO WORK REGARDLESS OF THAT, JUST COMMENT OUT THE IF(ISSET(... BLOCK...
$editURL = "edit.php"; //EDIT URL HERE 
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    //ASSIGN THE ID TO A VARIABLE FOR BUILDING THE URL LATER IN JS... 
    //THE DEFAULT ID IS 1 BUT YOU CAN DECIDE WITH YOUR OWN LOGIC 
    $defaultID =  ($dID = intval(trim($_REQUEST['id']))) ? $dID : 1;
?>

<script>
    function confirmEdit(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var cf=confirm("do you want to delete Y/N");
        var id=<?php echo defaultID; ?>;
        if(cf){
            //i want to call code edit of php
            //HERE'S THE CODE YOU MAY NEED TO RUN;
            if(id){
                //RETURN TRUE SO THAT THE SCRIPT WITH LINK TO THE APPROPRIATE URL
                return true;

                // OR REDIRECT WITH JAVASCRIPT TO EDIT PAGE WITH APPROPRIATE ID
                //window.location = "" + <?php echo $editURL; ?> + "?id=" + id; //YOU ALREADY HAVE THE EDIT URL... JUST APPEND THE QUERY-STRING WITH ID TO USE IN THE EDIT PAGE
                 // You might also just (without redirecting) return true here so to that the page continues like you just clicked on the link itself...
            }
        }
    } 
</script>
<?php
    }
?>


<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- THE FORM TAG IS NOT NECESSARY IN THIS CASE SINCE YOUR ANCHOR TAGS HAVE THE EXACT URL YOU WANT ASSOCIATED WITH THEM... AND YOU DON'T EVEN NEED JAVASCRIPT IN THIS CASE... BECAUSE THE HREF OF THE LINKS ARE HARD-CODED... -->
        <!-- <form name="frm" method="post" action="edit.php"> -->
            <a class='class-4-css' onclick="confirmEdit();" id='dynamic-id-based-btn-1' href="edit.php?id=1">Edit Page 1 </a> <br>
            <a class='class-4-css' onclick="confirmEdit();" id='dynamic-id-based-btn-2' href="edit.php?id=2">Edit Page 2</a> <br>
            <a class='class-4-css' onclick="confirmEdit();" id='dynamic-id-based-btn-3' href="edit.php?id=3">Edit Page 3</a> <br>
        <!-- </form> -->

    </body>
</html>
```

So, now clicking on any of the Links will Ask me to confirm if I want to delete the Resource or not. If I choose yes, then the appropriate page is loaded for the Process...

Answer (score -1):

not sure if the other answers really answered your question, this was my problem too, then I experimented and here's what I came up with:

.

confirmation in php :

```
    $Confirmation = "<script> window.confirm('Your confirmation message here');
        </script>";

    echo $Confirmation;

        if ($Confirmation == true) {
    your code goes here
    }
```

that's all, other people might look for this, you're welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

I was looking to simply have a confirmation box in php before triggering POST isset without going through javascript:

```
echo "<input id='send_btn' type='submit' value='previous'
name='previous' OnClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to go
to previous');\" >";
```

This appeared for me to be the easiest solution.